# Разделы с количеством товаров

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

Добрый день! Подскажите плиз. Есть разделы каталога, 3 уровня вложенности, к разделам привязаны товары, необходимо для каждого раздела вывести количество товаров находящимся в нем с учете дочерних подразделов. Количество товаров меняется в зависимости от фильтра, например если указан определенный бренд или ценовой диапазон.

Читал про [агрегацию](http://djbook.ru/rel1.9/topics/db/aggregation.html) но не понял как это применить к MPTT

Как это можно сделать средствами Django orm, и в будущем в базе будет около миллиона товаров, как это сделать наиболее оптимально с запасом на такое количество.

База используется Postgresql-9.5, все это работает на Centos 7, Python 3, Django 1.10.2

Ниже приведены модельки разделов и товаров, а также код из шаблона

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField('Раздел', max_length=100)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True)

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['sort']

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Раздел'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Разделы'

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s%s' % ('- ' * self.level, self.name)


class Product(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    name = models.CharField('Название', max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField('Цена')

    size = models.ManyToManyField(Size)
    color = models.ManyToManyField(Color)

    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Brand, blank=True)
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Company, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Товар'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Товары'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

def product_list(request, category_slug=False):
    category = None
    object_list = Product.objects.all()

    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        object_list = object_list.filter(parent__in=category.get_descendants(include_self=True))

    paginator = Paginator(object_list, 3)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    sections = Category.objects.all()

    try:
        products = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        products = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        products = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(
        request,
        'catalog/product_list.html',
        {
            'page': page,
            'category': category,
            'sections': sections,
            'products': products
        }
    )

{% load mptt_tags %}
<ul>
    {% recursetree sections %}
        <li{% if node == category %} class="active"{% endif %}>
            <a href="/catalog/{{ node.slug }}/">{{ node.name }}</a>
            {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
            <ul>
                {{ children }}
            </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endrecursetree %}
</ul>
```

хочется получить что то вроде

```
<a href="/catalog/{{ node.slug }}/">{{ node.name }} ({{ node.cnt }})</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#получаем список идентификторов всех низлежащих категорий, включая интересующую нас
ids = Category.objects.get(pk=category_id).get_descendants(include_self=True).values_list('id')
#получаем количество товаров, имеющих родителем категорию с идентификатором  входящим в список полученный строкой выше
product_count = Product.objects.filter(parent_id__in=ids).count()
```

**UPDATE:**

В предыдущий месяц мне пришлось плотно работать с SQL, что позволило прокачать свои знания, и я таки смог написать запрос возвращающий список категорий с количеством товаров принадлежащих этой категории или любой из дочерних.

```
SELECT name, cp.p_count FROM catalog_category AS cc
INNER JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT cc.id AS id, SUM(products) AS p_count FROM (
    SELECT cc.id AS parent_id, category_id, COUNT(id) AS products
    FROM catalog_product
    WHERE category_id IN (
      SELECT id FROM catalog_category
      WHERE lft <= cc.rght AND lft >= cc.lft AND tree_id = cc.tree_id)
      GROUP BY category_id
    ) AS sub_cс
  GROUP BY parent_id
) AS cp
USING(id) ORDER BY name;
```

Comment: Дополните код комментариями, что вы сделали, как и почему.

Comment: @Kromster но это же элементарно.

Comment: Ок.. так я могу получить количество товаров для конкретного раздела, во views.py у меня выбираются все категории
sections = Category.objects.all()
Мне вышеприведенный пример нужно поместить в цикл чтоли?
for s in sections:
   ...

Comment: Два запроса на количество категорий - очень не оптимальный вариант. Но боюсь, что не существует метода сделать такую выборку оптимальнее. Если только перенести нагрузку на этап записи данных в базу: добавить в `Category` поле для хранения количества товаров в дочерних группах и при занесении в базу новых товаров это поле пересчитывать.

Comment: Это сработало бы если это нужно было бы просто выводить количество товаров для каждого раздела как статические данные, а в моей задаче подразумевается что эта цифра (количество товаров с учетом всех подразделов) будет меняться от примененного фильтра. Учитывая все выше сказанное - будет ли разумно для этих целей использовать чистый Sql запрос(ы) для получения нужного результата и обеспечения максимальной производительности?

Comment: К сожалению, ничего не могу сказать по поводу применения SQL совместно с MPTT, никогда не пробовал. Сомневаюсь, что удастся получить сколько-нибудь серьёзный прирост производительности, но сложность возрастёт настолько, что впору будет задумываться о выносе запросов в хранимую процедуру. Могу и ошибаться, конечно.